# Android Resizing Radio Button programmatically

Tags: android, radio-button

Is it possible to assign width and height to RadioButton in Android programmatically? I know we can do it by using scaleX and scaleY properties. What I am looking for is, if user gives a width and height in int, how can we apply to the RadioButton?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myRadioButton.getButtonDrawable().setBounds(/* play around with the bounds */);
```

The documentation on the [Drawable class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#setBounds(android.graphics.Rect)) says this is how you change a Drawable's size. Unfortunately, it's not really clear *how* it works, so you'll need to play around.

Comment: I tried this, and I guess its changing the layout boundaries, but not actually affecting the RadioButton size. 
Plus I am creating a custom RadioButton, so I am trying to set its size from the Custom component itself

Comment: What does your custom RadioButton extend?

Comment: It extends RadioButton from Android

Comment: @TheWanderer...unfortunately the setBounds is not helping either

Comment: Maybe `setPadding()`?

Comment: Added setPadding, but its not changing the size of the button itself

Answer (score 0):

Since [RadioButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton), inherits from [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView), you can use `myRadioButton.setHeight(int pixels)` and `.setWidth(int pixels)` to set the size of the entire button area, but not the text nor the selection circle.  To change the size of the content but not the overall area, you can use `.setScaleX(float scale)` and `.setScaleY()` you will change the text and selection circle, but not the button area.

So to change both the button area and the size of its contents:

```
    int desiredWidth = 500;  // Set to your desired width.
    int currentWidth = radioButton.getWidth();
    radioButton.setScaleX(desiredWidth / currentWidth);
    radioButton.setWidth(desiredWidth);
```

And likewise for the height.

If you want to maintain the aspect ratio, set just the desired width and then:

```
desired_height = desired_width * current_height / current_width
```

Like this:

```
    int desiredWidth = 500;
    int currentHeight = radioButton.getHeight();
    int currentWidth = radioButton.getWidth();
    int desiredHeight = desiredWidth * currentHeight / currentWidth;
    radioButton.setScaleY(desiredHeight / currentHeight);
    radioButton.setHeight(desiredHeight);
    radioButton.setScaleX(desiredWidth / currentWidth);
    radioButton.setWidth(desiredWidth);
```

It appears that the scale is adjusted from the center, without adjusting the position, so you might have to change the position (maybe this will be moot if you use a ConstraintLayout--with a LinearLayout my buttons bled off the screen when I resized them this way).

Comment: I agree that setScaleX and Y changes the size, the solution I am looking for is when the user specifies the height and width in int, how can I map it in setting the size?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your question better: using just an integer input, you want to set the size of the button AND its content, right?  I've edited by answer to address this.

Comment: Yes you are right in getting my question. I will try the solution and let you know. Thanks!!